# IE newer default version

Tags: internet-explorer, version, meta

I want IE to interpret my JavaScript code with the most recent version installed (Edge, 10). So I have added this tag into my head tag.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,10,9" />
```

My question: Instead of putting the versions one by one, ¿Is there any equivalent value to get the most recent version?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff955275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this will render in "the highest supported document mode of the browser".

Comment: Right !! There is no need to put all the versions.I mark it as the solution.
Thank you